# wix example of dual purpose (per-user or per-machine) package using ui

Tags: wix, package, windows-installer, wix3.5, wix3.7

Does any one have or know of a location of a sample Product.wxs on how to properly write Single Package Authoring?

I am trying to create a dual purpose (per-user or per-machine (user choice)) MSI.
I am looking for an example that inserts the registries in the right location (hkcu or hklm based on what the user chose)

Any examples?

Comment: Did you end up figuring this out?

Answer (score 0):

Specify HKMU as registry root - it points to HKCU respectively HKLM depending on how you install your MSI.

https://wixtoolset.org/docs/schema/wxs/registryvalue/#attributes